# Undesired rendering of <a></a> tags in between the elements

Tags: html, css, tags

Suddenly, after editing some css yesterday, `<a></a>` is automatically added after `<div>`, `<h1>` and other such elements, which is causing other big issues. Can anybody tell me what is causing this problem?

a blank `<a></a>` tag is generated, which is affecting other element after or before it.

You can take this page of the site I am working on -

http://www.celebvita.com/emily-bett-rickards-aka-felicity-smoak-figure-details-body-measurements-facts

Now go to the title element h1, after that you can see a blank `<a></a>` tag.
Or go to div with class kk-star-ratings  top-right rgt, a blank tag again.
and go to kksr-stars kksr-star gray, a unwilling a tag surrounding next div element, coming from nowhere.

No clue why tag is being rendered as such.

Comment: Typically if you see something wonky like that in a DOM inspector it means you have an HTML nesting error... Did you miss closing a `<a>` somewhere or some other tag?

Comment: I find it hard to see how a CSS change could affect raw html output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always remember using Validator or Inspector first. Your problem is you have too many errors, this particular one is really simple, check [Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.celebvita.com%2Femily-bett-rickards-aka-felicity-smoak-figure-details-body-measurements-facts&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&verbose=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3%20http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices#line-199):

> **Error Line 199**, Column 259: end tag for "a" omitted, but OMITTAG NO
>   was specified

```
;Felicity Smoak&#8217; figure details, body measurements &#038; facts<a></h1>
```

Anyway, this is an extremely minor fix, but adding this link an answer because you have A LOT of errors you need to check as well

Comment: yes, validator did it, some omitted tags caused this problem, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you use this two jQuery, this jQuery Conflict.
your issue is jquery conflict. 
http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js
http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js